# Regexp search and replace as variables in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I can't find a solution to this and its driving me crazy!

```
my $foo = qr/(\S+) (\X+)/;
my $bar = qr/$2/;

line =~ s/$foo/$bar/g
```

My problem is that `$bar` uses a previously defined value of `$2` rather than the `(\X+)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that second part of `s` is not regex, but rather string to replace regex found. You can achieve what you want with this (note `ee` double-eval option at the end):

```
my $foo = qr/(\S+) (\X+)/;
my $bar = '$2';             # no interpolation

$line =~ s/$foo/$bar/gee;   # first eval make $bar -> '$2', second replaces it
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried lots of things for the second argument including '\2', '$2' etc, I just didn't have the ee on the end.

Answer (score 1):

I guess value of $bar should just be a string and not a regex. The qr// doesn't look right there.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to bvr's suggestion you can use a sub ref for the replacement side of `s///`. This has the advantage of being precompiled (both the sub ref, and the substitution) as opposed to being recompiled for each match. In most cases this will be faster and more likely to catch any errors at compile time.

```
my $foo = qr/(\S+) (\X+)/;
my $bar = sub { $2 }; # or my $bar = \&some_replace_function;

$line =~ s/$foo/$bar->()/ge;
```